# service builder in Liferay 6.0.6portal + 6.1 plugins SDK not working

Tags: jsf-2, liferay-6

Hi i am developing Liferay faces portlet in Liferay 6.0.6 portal + 6.1 Plugins SDK environment. I am successfully running the portlet. But when i try to run service builder, it is raising errors.
Can any one help me.

Comment: what kind of errors? when: during deploy or during build-service? Nothing is clear from your question kindly provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem and the solution that my colleague suggested is to set up new project with jsf support using plugins SDK 6.1, and then move it back to plugins SDK 6.0.6.

On 6.0.6 Service Builder is working correctly, and JSF is still working properly because it was properly set up using plugins SDK 6.1